# How to make program stop when player dies?

Tags: python

I have made a simple program in which a player(a square box) is supposed to jump over a number of obstacles in order to get to the end. In my code, either when the player dies or wins, the program doesn't stop. Instead it keeps on going and loads the frames bit by bit. Also, I have a button class that I want to call to test it out but I am really confused on how to call a class. I tried searching it up but it was really confusing to me.

Here is my code for the buttons and the level:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
orange = (255, 128, 0)
vel = 5
x2 = 25
y2 = 405
x = 25
y = 405
red = (255, 0, 0)



class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self, win, outline=None):
        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            win.blit(text, (
            self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))

    def isOver(self, pos):
        # Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True

running = True
isjump = False
jumpcount = 8
question = input("There are 10 levels to this game. Which level do you want to play? ").lower()

def level6():
    surface = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 500))
    surface.fill((40, 252, 3))
    player = pygame.draw.rect(surface, white, pygame.Rect(x, y, 25, 25))
    x_speed, y_speed = 5, 4
    block = pygame.draw.rect(surface, red, pygame.Rect(400, 360, 20, 70))
    block2 = pygame.draw.rect(surface, red, pygame.Rect(450, 360, 20, 70))
    block3 = pygame.draw.rect(surface, red, pygame.Rect(500, 360, 20, 70))
    block4 = pygame.draw.rect(surface, red, pygame.Rect(550, 360, 20, 70))
    block5 = pygame.draw.rect(surface, red, pygame.Rect(600, 360, 20, 70))
    block6 = pygame.draw.rect(surface, red, pygame.Rect(650, 360, 20, 70))
    block7 = pygame.draw.rect(surface, red, pygame.Rect(700, 360, 20, 70))
    block8 = pygame.draw.rect(surface, red, pygame.Rect(750, 360, 20, 70))
    pygame.draw.line(surface, black, (0, 430), (1000, 430))
    pygame.display.flip()
    collision_tolerance = 10

    if player.colliderect(block):
        if abs(block.top - player.bottom) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block.bottom - player.top) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block.right - player.left) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block.left - player.right) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
    elif player.colliderect(block2):
        if abs(block2.top - player.bottom) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block2.bottom - player.top) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block2.right - player.left) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block2.left - player.right) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
    elif player.colliderect(block3):
        if abs(block3.top - player.bottom) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block3.bottom - player.top) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block3.right - player.left) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block3.left - player.right) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
    elif player.colliderect(block4):
        if abs(block4.top - player.bottom) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block4.bottom - player.top) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block4.right - player.left) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block4.left - player.right) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
    elif player.colliderect(block5):
        if abs(block5.top - player.bottom) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block5.bottom - player.top) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block5.right - player.left) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block5.left - player.right) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
    elif player.colliderect(block6):
        if abs(block6.top - player.bottom) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block6.bottom - player.top) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block6.right - player.left) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block6.left - player.right) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
    elif player.colliderect(block7):
        if abs(block7.top - player.bottom) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block7.bottom - player.top) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block7.right - player.left) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block7.left - player.right) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
    elif player.colliderect(block8):
        if abs(block8.top - player.bottom) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block8.bottom - player.top) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block8.right - player.left) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
        if abs(block8.left - player.right) < collision_tolerance:
            running = False
            surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
            largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
            end_screen = largefont.render('You Lost!', 1, (white))
            surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
```

Here is my while loop:

```
while running:

    pygame.time.delay(10)

    surface = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 500))
    player = pygame.draw.rect(surface, white, pygame.Rect(x, y, 25, 25))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 0:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 1000 - 50:
        x += vel

    if not(isjump):
        #if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 0:
            #y -= vel
        #if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 1000 - 50:
           # y += vel
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isjump = True

    else:
        if jumpcount >= -8:
            y -= (jumpcount * abs(jumpcount)) * 0.5
            jumpcount -= 0.5
        else:
            jumpcount = 8
            isjump = False

    if question == "level1" or question == "1" or question == "level 1":
        level1()
    elif question == "level2" or question == "2" or question == "level 2":
        level2()
    elif question == "level3" or question == "3" or question == "level 3":
        level3()
    elif question == "level4" or question == "4" or question == "level 4":
        level4()
    elif question == "level5" or question == "5" or question == "level 5":
        level5()
    elif question == "level6" or question == "6" or question == "level 6":
        level6()

    if (player.right > 950):
        surface.blit(surface, (0, 0))
        largefont = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 80)
        end_screen = largefont.render('You Win!', 1, (white))
        surface.blit(end_screen, (300, 100))
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.delay(1000)

pygame.quit()
```

There are multiple levels to this game, but they are mostly the same; I just made the coordinates different and made a few more kill blocks.

Comment: Have you tried adding the line `global running` at the top of (inside) the level6 function?

Comment: No, I didn't. This helped, but is it possible that you know how to sustain it for as long as I need until the player pressed X? Because I was thinking of adding some buttons for retrying and quitting the program